# Entity Framework do not persist data in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

here, i have a form that returns me a VALID client and i try to add it to my localDatabase and saveChanges(), but after closing the app the data does not stay in the database.

```
FacturationAppContext db;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    db = new FacturationAppContext();    
}

private void addNewClient(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddClient frmAdd = new AddClient(); 
    frmAdd.ShowDialog(); //form that returns a valid Client

    if (frmAdd.newClient != null)
    {
            db.Clients.Add(frmAjouter.newClient);                  
            db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

even by creating a client directly in the Method, the data (Client) does not stay in the database after closing the app.

EDIT: here is my connexion string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="FacturationAppContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CycloneFacturation.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

thanks, Charles

Comment: i'm not exactly remember name of property but in local database property change "COPY..." property to "if new.." like.

Comment: the code looks ok to me. are you sure you are verifying the existence of the client in the same database that it's being added to? perhaps check the connection strings and make sure. I would also try allocating `FracturationAppContext` in a `using` block inside `addNewClient`. It's better not to leave the connections dangling. If you need to optimise for performance later, you need to consider the resource management implications.

Comment: it seems that it add the data in the database, but only until the app is active.
i'll add the connexion string, but im pretty sure its the good one

Comment: i have seen that when i create a new model a copy of my database goes in bin/debug/ could that be the problem? if so, does it mean that when i start my App it take data from my real database, and when it save (saveChanges) it save in the other one... mmm...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
 private void addNewClient(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddClient frmAdd = new AddClient();
            frmAdd.ShowDialog(); //form that returns a valid Client
            using (db = new FacturationAppContext())
            {
                if (frmAdd.newClient != null)
                {
                    db.Clients.Add(frmAjouter.newClient);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

        }
```

The context in using

Comment: tried but still no save at the closing of the Application. the db only store data when the app is active